# Convert GraphQLResponse dictionary to python object

Tags: python, graphql, deserialization

I am running a graphql query using [aiographql-client](https://github.com/abn/aiographql-client) and getting back a `GraphQLResponse` object, which contains a raw `dict` as part of the response json data.

This dictionary conforms to a schema, which I am able to parse into a `graphql.type.schema.GraphQLSchema` type using [graphql-core's `build_schema` method](https://graphql-core-3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/utilities.html#graphql.utilities.build_schema).

I can also correctly get the `GraphQLObjectType` of the object that is being returned, however I am not sure how to properly deserialize the dictionary into a python object with all the appropriate fields, using the `GraphQLObjectType` as a reference.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I struggled with this a few years back as well and if I recall correctly, the only way to sanely do this was to manually map every expected field name to a corresponding dictionary entry in object's init or other function. Depending on your use case and data structure, a conversion to `dataclass` from said dict could be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I will probably do this as a last resort - it feels though like most of the work is already there given that `GraphQLObjectType` does have types, however if I'm not mistaken, there are some attributes in the raw dict which are not named identically to what the ObjectType would have so its a bit trickier to do it for the generic case if its not supported natively

Comment: Well I guess it's all known data so you could just create a "universal" mapping and parser from scratch - there aren't that many data types. It's some extra work compared to out-of-the-box libraries but should prove useful in case you decide to stick with the tech for longer. Also depending what your project is for, you could just run with the `GraphQLObjectType` objects instead of translating them to python native objects at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Pydantic to the heavy lifting in the parsing.
You can then either generate the models beforehand and select the ones you need based on `GraphQLObjectType` or generate them at runtime based on the definition returned by `build_schema`.

If you really must define your models at runtime you can do that with pydantic's `create_model` function described here : https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#dynamic-model-creation

For the static model generation you can probably leverage something like https://jsontopydantic.com/

If you share some code samples I'd be happy to give some more insights on the actual implementation

Comment: Generating beforehand is fine. One such example could be creating a model from github's schema which is available in graphq format [here](https://github.com/octokit/graphql-schema/blob/master/schema.graphql) and in json format [here])https://raw.githubusercontent.com/octokit/graphql-schema/master/schema.json). For instance, `ActorLocation` would be
```python
@dataclass
class ActorLocation:
    city: str
    country: str
...
```

If there are classes with more complex types they would be defined iteratively. I would think a utility to do this conversion exists already

Comment: I guess you could try to do that with https://github.com/qw-in/graphql-codegen-pydantic

Answer (score 1):

Coming back to this, there are some projects out there trying to achieve this functionality:

- https://github.com/denisart/graphql2python
- https://github.com/enra-GmbH/graphql-codegen-ariadne
- https://github.com/sauldom102/gql_schema_codegen

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same tedious problem while developing a personal project.
Because of that I just published a library which has the purpose of managing the mappings between python objects and graphql objects (python objects -> graphql query and graphql response -> python objects).

https://github.com/dapalex/py-graphql-mapper

So far it manages only basic query and response, if it will become useful I will keep implementing more features.

Try to have a look and see if it can help you